# Is there anyway to find out where javaws is located on a system

Tags: java, java-web-start

Many of our users have problem associating jnlp-files with javaws. I know there is a way to handle default program (at least with windoes) from commandline.

Is there anyway to find out where javaws is located, from inside an java applet?

Assuming you have the permission to do it.

EDIT: related question: Is Java and javaws always accessible from commandline (w/o having to change folder)

Comment: Do you really need to run the jnlp file with a double click? Perhaps you should create a simple batch/exe that does the task for you, use JWS's option to create desktop/start menu icons, or start it from the browser.

Comment: The users is downloading a dynamically generated jnlp-file from our site. Each is supposed to be run only once.. Starting from the browser still requires it to be associated?

Comment: Isn't the association created automatically when you install a new(er) version of Java? I know the older ones didn't, but I think they've changed that on 1.6+

Comment: Not sure, all I know is that I have lots of users complaining about Adobe Reader, or Word, trying to open the file :/

Comment: @Adam Ingmansson Verify what mime-type your web server assign to the .jnlp file, make sure it is correct, it should be application/x-java-jnlp-file . That might take care of many of such problems.

Comment: Apache is already handeling jnlp as Alication/x-java-jnlp-file from mime.types, also im setting the header manually from php as the file is dynamically generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed through the use of this snippet:

```
/* Add check for os to add any extension */
String javaws = System.getProperty("java.home")
                    + File.separator + "bin"
                    + File.separator + "javaws";
```